# ASP Classic: How split strings with 2 words or more?

Tags: string, split, substring

I need split I have a large economics text where I need splitstrings with 2 words or more, but I did not find any example on the Web for doing this task:

text:"Economics ranges from the very small to the very large. The study of individual decisions is called microeconomics. The study of the economy as a whole is called macroeconomics."

I need get the strings with 2 words or more with blank spaces at left and at right of the strings with 2 words or more. It is complicated, right?

Any help would be fully appreciated.

`x=split(text,"very small")` - Not works

I need get 'blank space "very small" blank space'

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can split on space, and return an array of all the words in your sentence, and then iterate the list and every second word return that word + the previous one

Comment: I can not do this last step:  iterate the list and every second word return that word + the previous one.

Comment: I cannot do this last step:  iterate the list and every second word return that word + the previous one. My code reads only 1 substrings at once, not 2 or 3 and output such words +neighbors substrings (words).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dim a
dim i

a = Split("this is a string")
for i=0 to ubound(a)
   if (i mod 2 =1) then
    MsgBox a(i-1) & " " & a(i)
   end if
next
```

Comment: Almost.          
<% dim a
dim i

a = Split("this is a string")
x = "is a"
for i=0 to ubound(a)
   if (i mod 2 =1) then
    MsgBox  a(i-1) & " x " & a(i)
 '             a(i-1)= this     is a     string = a(i)
   end if
next
%>

Comment: a(i-1) & " i " & a(i+1)  - where 'i' are the substrings and i-1 and i+1 the neighbours